# how to make two people communicate through the bot

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

I can’t figure out how to make two people communicate through the bot? That is, user1 >message> bot>message>user2 It turns out that the bot acts as an intermediary, passing messages from one user to another

I was thinking of making a database with a user ID, and if a person clicks on the "find a friend" button, the status of his ID = True And if 2 people with the True status, then they can communicate with each other, but there are no further thoughts at all .... Please help((

Answer (score 1):

**Remember, the Telegram bot will never be able to write to the user, if he himself did not activate this bot before.**

So. Your idea can be implemented as follows. The user enters the bot and is offered a choice (two buttons). The first button is "connect with a random user", and the second is "connect by id".
The first option: you accept a message from that user and duplicate it to another (and vice versa).
The second option: if the user enters the correct id of another user, he receives a notification about a successful connection, and then everything is the same as in the first option. If the id is incorrect - an error message.

For navigation I would use InlineKeyboard (or alternatively ReplyKeyboard). It turns out that the bot will be an intermediary between users.

Disadvantages for users: you (an outsider) will be able to save all correspondence and view them. View complete information about the user's account.
Benefits for users: They will be completely anonymous to each other.

I could say more about this, but I don't quite understand the point of creating a bot for such things

Comment: You explained everything correctly, but I myself know this theory, at the moment when I wanted to do this, I did not know how to apply the plan into action, or rather into the code.
Your answer didn't help at all, thanks.